# Dereference a rvalue shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, rvalue

I'm using a library which export a function like:

```cpp
// there is some type T
std::shared_ptr<T> foo(params);
```

and while the following code works fine:

```cpp
auto p = foo(params);
auto & v0 = *p;
// use v0 as a T's reference
```

the below crashes:

```cpp
auto & v1 = *foo(params);
// use v1 as a T's reference
```

So what is the difference between `v0` and `v1`? Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The object pointed at by a `shared_ptr` exists only as long as there is at least *one* shared pointer alive that still points at it.

In your example there is likely only one such pointer, and it's returned by `foo`.

For `v0`, `p` becomes the `shared_ptr` keeping the object alive.

For `v1`, there is only a *temporary* shared pointer that exists only for the duration of `v1`'s initialization. The pointer and object being pointed at are gone by the time you use the reference, making it a dangling one at the point of use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, short and precise answer. I've though that the dereference may help "pin" the `T`'s object from shared pointer instances, but it's not.

Comment: @TaThanhDinh - Nah, the pointer pins the object, not the other way around. A reference to the object is still a "dumb" reference.

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
auto & v1 = *foo(params);
```

is a potential *undefined behavior*.

The function `foo` probably construct a `std::shared_ptr` inside and returns it to the caller as a temporary object (technically a *prvalue*) which is supposed to be assigned to some variable.

You don't assign the smart pointer of your expression to any variable. However, you grab the object pointed by (using the `*` operator) and assign it to the reference `v1`.

At the end of the expression evaluation the temporary `std::shared_ptr` will be destroyed and (being a smart pointer) the object pointed as well.

Therefore, `auto & v1` is referring to a destroyed object and accessing to it is an undefined behavior (producing a segmentation fault in the majority of cases).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that accessing a destroyed object is an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `p` remains in scope, holding a reference to the object and thereby keeping it alive. In your second example, the `shared_ptr` is destroyed after `v1` is created, which destroys the object (assuming it was the only reference) and leaving `v1` pointing to unallocated memory.